# sed: couldn't write 26 items to stdout: Broken pipe

Tags: bash, sed

i have the following command:

```
cat input.txt | awk '{print $1, $6}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | sed 's/"//g'| head -10
```

i get the desired output, but i get this error

```
sed: couldn't write 26 items to stdout: Broken pipe
```

where input.txt is something like:

```
192.168.2.20 - - [28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0300] "GET /cgi-bin/try/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3395
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2006:10:22:04 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2216
```

what am i missing

Comment: `head` closes the input before `sed` could write it. Just first `head -n10` and then use `sed` or maybe try `tr -d \"`.

Comment: By creating a test file with 1500 lines as your example, your command runs without error in my Debian equipped with `bash 4.4.23` , `gnu sed 4.5` and `gnu coreutils (head - sort) 8.30`

Comment: Also tangentially avoid the [useless useeof `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: and if you tell us what it is you're trying to do (in a new question with it's own sample input/output) then I expect someone can show you how do do it without 27 commands, 15 pipes and the batman symbol...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @KamilCuk said in a comment, this is happening because `head -10` only reads the first 10 lines from the pipeline (plus maybe some input buffering), and then closes it; if the input is big enough, this happens before `sed` has written everything into the pipe (and the pipe's buffer isn't big enough to absorb the extra). So whether this happens or not depends on the input size, OS and its parameters (which determine the pipe's characteristics), `sed`'s behavior on having its output dropped, etc. Just changing things up a bit may be enough to avoid the problem, for example:

```
...sort -nr | tr -d '"' | head -10       # use `tr` instead of `sed` -- it may behave differently
...sort -nr | head -10 | sed 's/"//g'    # swap `head` and `sed` -- now `sort`'s output is dropped
```

And here's one that *will* avoid the error:

```
...sort -nr | sed '11,$ d; s/"//g'
```

The way this works is it tells `sed` to discard lines 11 through the end of input ("$"), but since it discards them *after* reading them (rather than never reading them in the first place, like `head -10`), `sort`'s entire output gets read and no error occurs.

BTW, as @triplee pointed out, using `cat` at the beginning of the pipeline is useless; you should have `awk` read the file directly, like this:

```
awk '{print $1, $6}' input.txt | ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Approach #1:  Move sed to the end

```
cat input.txt | awk '{print $1, $6}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10 | sed 's/"//g'
```

This is semantically the same.  By putting sed at the end, you get the formatting you desire, but you'll avoid the error message.

Approach #2:  Ignore the error messages.

```
cat input.txt | awk '{print $1, $6}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | sed 's/"//g' 2>/dev/null | head -10
```

This is rather brute force and may result in you missing another issue in the future.